# In a Highcharts Combination chart (line and column), is it possible that tu column serie be the principal?

Tags: highcharts

I have a combined chart (line and column).  The linear series has the labels down each point, however, I need the labels be down the column series.  Is this possible at all?

```
   series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2],
            pointPlacement : 'on'
        },  {
            type : 'column',
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9],
            pointPlacement : 'between'
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean datalabels, setting them in a bottom is not officially supported (you can vote for this option here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2660291-datalabel-inside-column-option), but you can use small workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/W9ZUQ/6/

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series,
                s1 = series[1].data,
                i = 0,
                l = s1.length;
            for (; i < l; i++) { 
                s1[i].dataLabel.attr('y', 290);
            }
        }
    }
},
```